# python one2many/many2one key error

Tags: python, odoo, one-to-many

this is my code

verbindingen.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
import logging

class verbindingen(osv.osv):
_name = "verbindingen.verbindingen"
_description = "De verbindingen"

_columns = {
    #'customer_id' : fields.one2many('res.partner','x_customer_id','Customer ID'),
    'kanaal_id' : fields.one2many('verbindingen.kanalen', 'verbinding_id'),
    'aansluitadres_straat' : fields.char('Aansluitadres straat', size = 40),
    'aansluitadres_huisnummer' : fields.char('Aansluitadres huisnummer', size = 6),
    'aansluitadres_postcode' : fields.char('Aansluitadres postcode', size = 6),
    'aansluitadres_toevoeging' : fields.char('Aansluitadres toevoeging', size = 6),
    'aansluitadres_plaats' : fields.char('Aansluitadres plaats', size = 40),
    'verbinding_type_id' : fields.one2many('verbindingen.types','verbinding_id','Verbinding type'),
    'leveranciers_id' : fields.integer('Leveranciers ID', size = 20),
    'service_id' : fields.integer('Service ID', size = 20),
    'dikader' : fields.integer('Dikader'),
    'management_ip' : fields.char('Management ip', size = 15),
    'management_username' : fields.char('Management username', size = 20),
    'management_psswd' : fields.char('Management password', size = 20),

    }
```

kanalen.py

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv


class kanalen(osv.osv):
_name = "verbindingen.kanalen"
_description = "Kanalen van de verbindingen"

_columns = {
    'type_kanaal' : fields.selection([], 'Type kanaal'),
    'verbinding_id' : fields.many2one('verbindingen.verbindingen'),
    'VLAN_ID' : fields.integer('Vlan ID'),
    'MAC' : fields.char('MAC Adress', size = 17),
    'IP' : fields.char('IP-adres'),
    'VCI/VPI' : fields.char('VCI/VPI'),
    'status' : fields.selection([('active', 'Active'),('inactive', 'Inactive')], 'Status')
```

}

When I try to install this module I get a KeyError: 'verbinding_id' error.
I have no clue what is wrong with my code.

Comment: verbindingen.py file convert into new api odoo V8 OR kanalen.py convert into openerp V7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created two models as I see from your code i.e. `verbindingen.verbindingen` and `verbindingen.kanalen` then where is the `verbindingen.types` .?

if is it not there then create model `verbindingen.types` and new m2o field there or remove the from relation field

```
'verbinding_type_id' : fields.one2many('verbindingen.types','verbinding_id','Verbinding type')
```

Comment: well there is a verbindingen.types but I was testing the module with verbindingen and kanalen. My code should still work without types. Its just a one2many- many2one relation

Comment: see if you haven't define verbindingen.types in your code then the how field will relate with the module. you see field will trying to field the related module to relate it with the module so it cannot find the related feild that is 'verbinding_id' so its giving key error, or if you have defined it later please try reinstalling the module not upgrade. tell me if you need more

Comment: I complete forgot I didnt comment out the verbindingen.types code in my xml file. Its working now. Thanks for the help